# I'm trying to enable error squiggles in VS Code and it's not working and throwing an error message

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, visual-c++

I'm coding in C++ in VS Code and when the code is wrong, the error squiggles aren't appearing. And when I go into the command palette and use `C/C++: Enable Error Squiggles` I get the following:

`Command 'C/C++: Enable Error Squiggles' resulted in an error (command 'C_Cpp.EnableErrorSquiggles' not found)`

I've tried restarting, checking for any updates, disabling and then enabling them. Nothing stops this error from coming up. I've also tried reinstalling it via VS Code but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 21):

If you had accidentally disabled it, try this...

1. Do Ctrl + p, and type "settings.json"
2. You will find the file which contains the value

   ```
   "C_Cpp.errorSquiggles": "Disabled"
   ```
3. Change it into Enabled.

Answer (score 9):

Go to the setting by using "ctrl" + "," . Then search for error squiggles.
Take care that there are 2 sections in the settings.
Firstly go to the "user" section.
Enable it or select "EnabledIfIncludesResolve".
Then check the "workspace" section too.
If it's disabled there, then enable it or select "EnabledIfIncludesResolve".
This will definitely work.

Answer (score 4):

1. Simply, go to settings by using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>comma</kbd>.
2. Search for `Error squiggles`.
3. Enable it or select `EnabledIfIncludesResolve`.
4. Then click on `Modified on Workspace`, if it is disabled, then enable it.

Comment: Is there anything else to try if this didn't work? I recently started having this issue after a Windows or VS Code update, not sure which...

Comment: The last step is what worked for me. +1

Answer (score 2):

My best solution is:

1. Find your workspace file name Like this settings.json
2. Then, open the settings.json file
3. Next, find (or) Search "C_Cpp.errorSquiggles": "Disabled" -This
   Option in settings.json
4. Change the value: "C_Cpp.errorSquiggles": "Disabled" -->
   "C_Cpp.errorSquiggles": "Enabled" -This OK! My Explain:
   find this Line:- "C_Cpp.errorSquiggles": "Disabled" and change the value of "Disabled" to "Enabled" OK!

Answer (score 2):

So basically, I did try enabling the error squiggles from the user as well as workbench settings. That didn't work.

A better solution which worked for me was uninstalling the intellisense from VScode and reinstalling through this link: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense

This worked like a charm.
Sometimes intellisense becomes less intelligent and needs a refresh!  :)

Answer (score 1):

It's easy all you need to do is press CTRL + , key on your keyboard and hit enter then type in the search box *"error squiggles"* and then you need to go to *C_Cpp: Error Squiggles* and make sure that the option is **enabled** or **enabledIfIncludesResolve** by default.

Answer (score -1):

Check to see if squiggles are enabled by going to the settings panel (ctrl+comma) then search for squiggles.  Make sure the option is checked and enabled.

The squiggles come from the [Intellisense](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense) engine.

Comment: It's just reworded existing [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69395427/6752050)

Answer (score -1):

First, go to the setting by using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>. Then search for *error squiggles* and make sure the option is enabled.

Comment: It's just reworded existing [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69395427/6752050)

Answer (score -2):

Check that the folder containing the file that is currently running is in the explorer, if not open the folder in the explorer and the error squiggle will appear.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).