# VS Code: How do I bring back the warnings (wavy lines)?

Tags: c, warnings

I am programming in C with Visual Studio Code, but I am still a beginner.

I set a mark at a point where I had to solve a problem and somehow a yellow bell or something showed up at the beginning of the code line and I inadvertently clicked on it.
Now there are all of the warnings and error signs (wavy colored lines under the code) are gone and I think my compiler does not work perfectly as well.

So, what did I do and how can I fix it?

Comment: Possible previous question: [I'm trying to enable error squiggles in VS Code and it's not working and throwing an error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62359501/im-trying-to-enable-error-squiggles-in-vs-code-and-its-not-working-and-throwin)

Comment: About "I think my compiler does not work perfectly". What makes you think that?

Comment: @WeatherVane I finished a small programm and wanted to compile it. I am pretty sure it is correct but it says: "expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '{' token [13, 1]" and that is right between "int main(void)" and the first "{". Maybe it thinks the whole content of the main function is part of the variables, which actually is "void", but that is clearly not the case.

Comment: If the compiler tells you there is something wrong with your program, you should beleive it. It is very, very unlikely that you found a fault in the compiler.

Comment: For your second suspicion on the compiler, please show us that small program in source.