# VS Code not showing underline errors

Tags: visual-studio-code, error-handling, underline

I have tried almost everything which includes <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> and on squiggles and all sort of that but still my underline errors are not getting on. Squiggles is not found in the cmd of vs code itself.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/267852/10926848) issue answer. Might be helpful for you :) If it is or not please let me know, so I can look for other ways to solve it. I'd be pleased to help

Comment: Also maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/70489551/10926848 this thread may help to you too.